# Background covering the whole page (CSS)

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I just switched from VSC to Adobe Dreamweaver and i don't know if I should keep it or not; but that's besides the point.

When I try to add a background to some text, it fills the whole screen with the background with the background, and if I try to change the width it only adds on to the background which is filling the whole screen.

I don't know if it's user error, something changed in HTML/CSS overnight or if it's because of the Dreamweaver display box thing on the top of my screen

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Container {
  padding: 25%;
  padding-left: 50%;
  padding-right: 50%;
  font-family: comfortaa;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  background: #00C3FF;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: url(http://www.incomeactivator.com/images/freebg5.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>index</title>
  <link href="file:///C|/Users/REDACTED/Documents/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
  <script>
    var __adobewebfontsappname__ = "dreamweaver"
  </script>
  <script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/comfortaa:n3:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="Container">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

p.s: let me know if you need a ss of the results I get.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the class, you can change the texts background color by adding
background-color: rgb(255, 236, 139)
in the h1 tag

Demo:

YOURTEXT

Answer (score 0):

It should work as expected if you apply the css to the **H1** tag:

```
.Container h1{}
```

You have used padding property incorrectly. [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)

Correct syntax:  **padding: top right bottom left**

```
padding:0 50% 0 50%;
```

**So the css should be:**

```
.Container{ margin: 0; }

.Container h1{  
  padding:0 50% 0 50%;
  font-family: comfortaa;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  background: #00C3FF;
}
```